# scrapy multiple execution by different urls

Tags: scrapy

I have an issue with my first spider. I want to process a robot by a lot of categories in tesco store:

```
class TescoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tescospider2"
    allowed_domains = ["ezakupy.tesco.pl"]
    categories= ['owoce-warzywa', 'nabial-i-jaja','pieczywo-cukiernia']
```

I am able to use a loop as this which is on the end of the `start_url` field to process the robot by all categories from my dictionary.

If I use this

```
categories[3]
```

it is working but if I try to use

```
categories[int(y) for y in range(0,2)]
```

it is not working.

I can not refer to list object using the loop but if I try to do it in this way it would not work:

```
start_urls =\
["https://ezakupy.tesco.pl/groceries/pl-PL/shop/"+categories[int(y) for y in 
range(0,2)]+"/all?page="+str(x) for x in range(1,2)]
data = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in how you construct the list comprehension for `start_urls`. Try it this way:

```
start_urls = [
    "https://ezakupy.tesco.pl/groceries/pl-PL/shop/" + categories[y] + "/all?page=" + str(x)
    for y in range(0, 2)
    for x in range(1, 2)
]
```